Is there a way to pull remotely generated XML, process it, and display it on a Managed WordPress page?
I need to get some XSQL generated XML data from a remote server, process it, and display it on a GoDaddy Managed WordPress page. (This is the website my workplace has to use for various reasons.) Currently, the data goes into a Google Sheet that's displayed in an iframe, but this is not a viable long-term solution.
The URL for the remote server contains the search calls for the XSQL database, including dates. The data is fire weather related, so passing the correct dates for observations and forecasts are necessary. I don't have an issue with making the URL in either PHP or JavaScript - getting the date, making the correct string from it, and injecting it into the URL.
Is there a way to do this given the restriction of the GoDaddy Managed WordPress environment and that we're not likely to talk the people who pay for the hosting into buying plugins?
I have looked at using JavaScript to fetch() the data, but doesn't work because of CORS, and using 'no-cors' returns an opaque object. Basically, it tells me "yes, there's a thing there." Naturally, not using 'no-cors' returns an error.
I have looked at PHP, but I don't understand how to make PHP work in the environment I'm given.
I am "learning" JavaScript and PHP piecemeal - a very old and unused background in one C class in college has served me well, as have Google and DuckDuckGo - so I'm very, very new to these codes.
Is there a way to create WordPress hooks to do what I want to do? I've been trying to wrap my brain around them, but not been very successful.
Note: the code below has had some information stripped and put in <>. It should still be obvious what's going on.
Failed JS Pull Method:
function getTodaysDate() {
    var m_names = new Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC");
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate().toString();
    if (curr_date.length == 1) {
        curr_date = `0${curr_date}`;
    }
    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var curr_year = year.toString().substr(2.2);
    var today = `${curr_date}-${m_names[curr_month]}-${curr_year}`;
    return today;
}

function getYesterday() {
    var m_names = new Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC");
    var d = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));
    var last_date = d.getDate().toString();
    if (last_date.length == 1) {
        last_date = `0${last_date}`;
    }
    var last_month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var last_year = year.toString().substr(2.2);
    var yesterday = `${last_date}-${m_names[last_month]}-${last_year}`;
    return yesterday;
}
        
async function locWx() {
    var urlDate= getYesterday();
    var locUrl= `https://<sanitized site and directories>/<filename>.xsql?stn=&sig=LOC&type=&start=${urlDate}&end=${urlDate}&time=&priority=&fmodel=&sort=&ndays=&user=`;
    console.log(locUrl);
    var Res= fetch(locUrl);
    var response= await Res;
    var xmlText= await response.text();
    return xmlText;
    console.log(xmlText);

/*fetch(locUrl, {mode: 'no-cors'})
    .then(response => {
        if(!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(xmlText => {
        const parser = newDOMParser();
        const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText, 'text/xml');
        consle.log(xmlDoc);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
        console.log(alfUrl);
    })*/
}

Failed jQuery Method:
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var m_names = new Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC");
            var d = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1));
            var last_date = d.getDate().toString();
            if (last_date.length == 1) {
                last_date = `0${last_date}`;
            }
            var last_month = d.getMonth();
            var year = d.getFullYear();
            var last_year = year.toString().substr(2.2);
            var yesterday = `${last_date}-${m_names[last_month]}-${last_year}`;
            var locUrl = `https://<sanitized site and directories>/<filename>.xsql?stn=&sig=LOC&type=&start=${yesterday}&end=${yesterday}&time=&priority=&fmodel=&sort=&ndays=&user=`;
            console.log(locUrl);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                mode: "no-cors",
                url: locUrl,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(xml){
                    console.log("here");$
                        $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
                            var number = $(this).find('firstField').text();
                            var name = $(this).find('secondField').text();
                            var lat = $(this).find('thirdField').text();
                            $('<tr></tr>').html('<th>' +number+ '</th><td>' +name+ '</td><td>' +lat+ '</td>').appendTo('#myTable');
                        });
                }
            });
        });

I have to research PHP again. I can't find where I had an attempt at the code since I don't have a good testing environment. (I'll keep looking for one.)
